# pH value of a buffer solution of HClO and NaClO

Tags: solutions, ph

So,

I have 200mL of HClO 0,64M.

I mix it with 0,1mol of NaClO.

How should I calculate the pH?

My question is about this: should I keep attention about changes made to the solution volume after adding NaClO?

So far this is what I've done.

Considering:

$\ce{NaClO + H2O -> Na+ + ClO-}$

With n<sub>(NaClO)</sub> = n<sub>(ClO<sup>-</sup>)</sub> = 0.1mol,

I calculated the molarity of the conjugate base:

[ClO<sup>-</sup>] = 0.1mol/0.2L = 0.5M.

Then I applied the Henderson-Hesselbalch equation:

pH = pKa + log([ClO<sup>-</sup>]/[HClO]) = 7.53 + log(0.781M) = 7.422

In this case I didn't consider the variation to the solution volume due to the addition of NaClO. So, is this correct?

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: I'm a college student, this is not a homework question. I've already solved it but I'm not sure about the result. I would like to compare my result with someone who know exactly how to solve it.

Comment: Please see the homework link in my above comment to learn what qualifies as a homework type of question and how to ask one. You can get help with this here, you just need to follow the guidelines. Best of luck.

Comment: In addition to the problem that this would be considered a homework question, it also qualifies as an [amirite question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3396) (seeks to consider confirmation or clarification on an already derived answer) which we have determined to be a bad fit for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Everything is correct, except that when you take the ratio of concentrations in the H-H equation that ratio is not in moles.   It's just a number, because you divide moles by moles .  Rule of thumb: logarithms and exponential should never involve anything with units.  So don't include the molar unit under the logarithm and you're good.